# Kivy installing build dependencies...error

Tags: python, pip, kivy

I'm new to python and I want to install kivy. When I do `pip install kivy` it gives me following error. I've python 3.10.0 and pip 21.3.1. and also I want to mention that I don't get any error like this when installing other modules.

```
Collecting kivy
Using cached Kivy-2.0.0.tar.gz (23.7 MB)
Installing build dependencies ... error
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
command: 'C:\Users\bamba\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe' 
'C:\Users\bamba\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-standalone-pip-kuk2dvss\__env_pip__.zip\pip' install -- 
 ignore-installed --no-user --prefix 'C:\Users\bamba\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env- 
 3zq1w_aw\overlay' --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i 
 https://pypi.org/simple -- setuptools wheel 'cython>=0.24,<=0.29.21,!=0.27,!=0.27.2' 
 'kivy_deps.gstreamer_dev~=0.3.1; sys_platform == "win32"' 'kivy_deps.sdl2_dev~=0.3.1; 
 sys_platform == "win32"' 'kivy_deps.glew_dev~=0.3.0; sys_platform == "win32"' 
 'kivy_deps.gstreamer~=0.3.1; sys_platform == "win32"' 'kivy_deps.sdl2~=0.3.1; sys_platform == 
 "win32"' 'kivy_deps.glew~=0.3.0; sys_platform == "win32"'
       cwd: None
  Complete output (10 lines):
  Collecting setuptools
    Using cached setuptools-58.3.0-py3-none-any.whl (946 kB)
  Collecting wheel
    Using cached wheel-0.37.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (35 kB)
  Collecting cython!=0.27,!=0.27.2,<=0.29.21,>=0.24
    Using cached Cython-0.29.21-py2.py3-none-any.whl (974 kB)
  Collecting kivy_deps.gstreamer_dev~=0.3.1
    Using cached kivy_deps.gstreamer_dev-0.3.2-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl (3.9 MB)
  ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement kivy_deps.sdl2_dev~=0.3.1 (from versions: 0.4.2, 0.4.3)
  ERROR: No matching distribution found for kivy_deps.sdl2_dev~=0.3.1
```

Comment: don't use the newest Python because some modules may not be ready for this version. Authors need time to recompile mdoules for new Python. it is better to wait few months and still use `3.8` (eventually `3.9`) at this moment.

Comment: Thank You !!! I downloaded version 3.9.0 and kivy installed...

Answer (score 0):

First got to [here](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/gettingstarted/installation.html)

After go to window for pip and create venv and open your cmd and use this python -m pip install "kivy[base] @ [https://github.com/kivy/kivy/archive/master.zip"](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/archive/master.zip%22)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).